# QueryFailedError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction [typeorm]

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

//Code//
const queryRunnerItem = this.itemsRepository.manager.connection.createQueryRunner();
const queryRunnerProductCategoryItem = this.productCategoryItemRepository.manager.connection.createQueryRunner();
const queryRunnerProductStock = this.productStockRepository.manager.connection.createQueryRunner();

```
try {
  await queryRunnerItem.connect();
  await queryRunnerItem.startTransaction();
  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.connect();
  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.startTransaction();
  await queryRunnerProductStock.connect();
  await queryRunnerProductStock.startTransaction();

 
  const newProduct = this.itemsRepository.create({
    name: body.name,
    detail: body.detail,
  })

  await queryRunnerItem.manager.save(newProduct);
  const newProductCategoryItem = this.productCategoryItemRepository.create({
    itemId: newProduct.id,
    productCategoryId: body.productCategoriesId
  })

  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.manager.save(newProductCategoryItem)

  const newproductStock = this.productStockRepository.create({
    quality: 0,
    itemId: newProduct.id,
  })
  await queryRunnerProductStock.manager.save(newproductStock)

  await queryRunnerProductStock.commitTransaction();
  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.commitTransaction();
  await queryRunnerItem.commitTransaction();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  await queryRunnerProductStock.rollbackTransaction();
  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.rollbackTransaction();
  await queryRunnerItem.rollbackTransaction();
  throw new HttpException("Can't Create Coupon", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
} finally {
  await queryRunnerProductStock.release();
  await queryRunnerProductCategoryItem.release();
  await queryRunnerItem.release();

}
```

}